# Foreign keys on Insert with Struts2 / Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, struts2, foreign-keys

I'm new user of Struts 2 w/ hibernate.
I have 2 tables : "Client" and "Coordonnees" (french word) 
In my table "Client", I have a FK named "coordonnees_id", that references field "id" from table "Coordonnees"
I created an insert form like this :

File add.jsp

```
<s:form method="post" action="create">
    <s:textfield cssClass="" label="Nom" name="client.nom" />
    <s:textfield cssClass="" label="Prénom" name="client.prenom" />
    ....
    <s:textfield cssClass="" label="Email" name="coordonnees.email" />
    <s:textfield cssClass="" label="Adresse" name="coordonnees.adresse" />
    <s:submit value="Insert" />
</s:form>
```

File ClientAction.java

```
private Client client;
private ClientManager clientManager;
private Coordonnees coordonnees;
private CoordonneesManager coordonneesManager;

public String create() {

    client = getClient();
    coordonnees = getCoordonnees();

    try {
        clientManager.insert(client);
        coordonneesManager.insert(coordonnees);
        return SUCCESS;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ERROR;
    }
}
```

File CoordonneesManager.java

```
public boolean insert(Coordonnees coordonnees) {

    session = MyHibernateUtil.currentSession();
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    try {
        session.save(coordonnees);
        log.info("Enregistrement de : " + getClass());
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e);
        return false;
    } finally {
        tx.commit();
        MyHibernateUtil.closeSession();
    }
}
```

In my Client.hbm.xml file :

```
<many-to-one class="model.Coordonnees" fetch="select" name="coordonnees">
    <column name="coordoonnees_id"/>
</many-to-one>
```

Here is my problem :
When I submit my form, I would like to insert data into table Client (of course ...), into table "Coordonnees" (it works fine), and I would like to get the "id" I just created from table Coordonnees and insert it into my table Client (field "coordonnees_id" => my FK).

Is there an easy option in struts2 to do that ? Of course I can perform a select query on my last insert in table Coordonnees, get the id and update my table Client ... But it's not the point, I would like Struts to do this for me (if it's possible of course).

Thank you all for your help :)

Comment: If you have your objects and mappings set up correctly, Hibernate should take care of making sure foreign keys are all set up correctly when you insert an object graph.

Comment: Hi cdeszaq, that was my question : how can I correctly map those elements please ? I am a novice with that technology :/. Is this in my "Patient.hbm.xml" file ? Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

I believe that persisting these two objects should happen in the same transaction. You should first persists the parent i.e. the `coordonnees` then flash it to get the primary key and then set the relation in the child object. Afterwards persist the child.

Comment: For the moment, I do this : session.save(coordonnees);
            client.setCoordonnees(coordonnees);
            session.save(client); I can deal with it, but, is there a way to do this automaticlly or is this the only way ? Thank you for your answer unixorn